# OO PHP mysqli database connection

Tags: php, object, mysqli

I have an issue with the code below, so I have created a database connection and running it in CMD appears to be working fine, but I am not 100% how to test it out ? Can someone please point if out if its fine, Im still a newbie in PHP

```
<?php

class databaseConnection
{
    private $host;
    private $databasename;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    public $mysqli;

    //forcing the data to be given to the object (using the constructor)
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->databaseConnect();
    }

    private function databaseConnect()
    {
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->username = '$$$$$';
        $this->password = '$$$$$';
        $this->databasename = '$$$$$$$';

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databasename);
        return $this->mysqli;
        echo('Connection Succeeded');
    }
}
```

Comment: try getting the class in separate file and using a select statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we ever check for mysqli\_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808332/should-we-ever-check-for-mysqli-connect-errors-manually)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this style for OOP.
declare your variable first, like :

```
$localhost = 'localhost'; 
$user      = 'user'; 
$pw        = 'pass';
$db        = 'database';
$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost,$user,$pw,$db);
```

For Reference : [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't actually answer the question... nor does it check if connection is successful ..

Answer (score -1):

Everything after 'return' won't get executed btw.

You should wrap the '$this->mysqli;' inside an if.

```
if($this->mysqli){
  echo 'OK';
} else {
  echo 'error';
  echo $this -> mysqli -> error;
}
```

The mysqli returns a Boolean if the connect was succesful.

To test the actual connection, maybe add a 'test' function that selects 1 record from a default table.

Comment: hi Bert Thanks, tried this out but still cannot see OK or error returned? 
  if ( $this->mysqli){
     echo 'OK';
  }else {
   echo 'error';
   echo $this -> mysqli -> error;

Comment: Did you put it before your 'return $this_.mysqli'? Is your databaseConnection() getting initialized somewhere like '$conn = new databaseConnection();' otherwise the constructor won't get triggered?

Comment: fixed! Thanks a million :)